# The meaning of SUP bit in page tables

Tags: process, kernel, x86-64, paging, page-tables

One of the page table entry attributes is the SUP bit.
I read in couple documents that:

> "if the SUP is set then only a process in kernel mode can access that page. Versus if it is not set then a process in user mode can access it."

I find this statement confusing, because a process in kernel mode can be a process within which a user program is running or a kernel program (user process vs system process). So which does the statement refer to? Or is it both as long as the process is currently executing in kernel mode?

If this statement refers also to processes within which a user program is running(user process), then we already know that memory access can only be made when the process switches into kernel mode, then there is no need to have the SUP bit.

My guess is that the SUP bit is meant to say that this page is accessed only by system processes (excluding user processes running in kernel mode), but I am not sure as I don't have knowledge about how the kernel code is stored in memory and if it is paged and how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ever you have any doubt about the working of an Intel CPU consult the [Manuals](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), not any random internet page<sup>1</sup>.

Paging access rights are described in Section 4.6.

---

The CPU distinguishes the privilege of an *address* and of an *access* (to an address), each privilege is either a *user-mode* or *supervisor-mode* (where supervisor-mode is intended to be more privileged).

**Access mode**

> Every access to a linear address is either a **supervisor-mode access** or a **user-mode access**. For all instruction
>   fetches and most data accesses, this distinction is determined by the current privilege level (CPL): **accesses made
>   while CPL < 3 are supervisor-mode accesses, while accesses made while CPL = 3 are user-mode accesses.**
>   Some operations implicitly access system data structures with linear addresses; the resulting accesses to those
>   data structures **are supervisor-mode accesses regardless of CPL**.
>   [...]
>   All these accesses are called **implicit supervisor-mode
>   accesses** regardless of CPL. Other accesses made while CPL < 3 are called **explicit supervisor-mode accesses**.

So when a program access a memory location, its CPL determine the access mode, user programs run at CPL = 3, thus they only perform user-mode accesses.
Kernel instead performs supervisor-mode accesses as it runs at CPL = 0.

**Address mode**

> Access rights are also controlled by the mode of a linear address as specified by the paging-structure entries
>   controlling the translation of the linear address. **If the U/S flag (bit 2) is 0 in AT LEAST ONE of the paging-structure
>   entries, the address is a supervisor-mode address**. Otherwise, the address is a **user-mode address**.

The *SUP* bit, formally known as *U/S*, then determines the mode of an address.
Since it is present in the PDE too (not only on the PTE), the idea is to take the more restrictive setting, thus a *U/S* set in one entry at any level suffices to make the address a supervisor-mode one.

**Access rights**

A *user-mode access* to a *supervisor-mode address* is always forbidden and an exception will be generated on attempt.

An access to the same mode address<sup>2</sup> and to a lower mode address<sup>3</sup> are generally permitted, they are not equal<sup>4</sup> though and there are a variety of flags altering the behavior of the CPU<sup>5</sup>.

The idea is that supervisor mode accesses can do whatever they want and to reduce the surface attack available to exploiters there are a few mechanisms to lower the privileges of an access.

---

<sup>1</sup> Including this one.
<sup>2</sup> User-mode access to user-mode address, supervisor-mode access to supervisor-mode address.
<sup>3</sup> Supervisor-mode access to user-mode address.
<sup>4</sup> Supervisor accesses can write to read only pages.
<sup>5</sup> For instance the *CR0.WP* flags disable write accesses to read only pages for supervisor accesses, the *NXE* bit disables fetching from a page with *XD* set.

Comment: so there are 2 different bits. A CPU register for the  CPL of the executing process. and the S/U bit in the PTE. If CPL=3, shouldn't we reject access to the memeory regardless of the value bit of the S/U?                                                                                        if CPL=0, then we check the S/U bit value. so 1) if CPL=0 and S/U=0 and this is a kernel process (not sure how we can determine this),then access permitted.  2) if CPL=0 and S/U=1 and this is a kernel process  then access permitted. 3) if CPL=0 and S/U=1 and this is a user process then access is permitted

Comment: i guess my confusion is with regards to case 2: User-mode access to user-mode address. Why would a user process process running in user mode be allowed to access memeory. isnt all memory access not allowed in CPL=3? and for that to happen the user process needs to be running in kernel mode?

Comment: @ijuio A program **needs** to access its own memory. Remember that *isolation* among processes is achieved by **not** mapping other processes pages entirely. So it's safe to let a user program access user-mode addresses, the kernel still confines it by choosing what to and not to map. Fun fact: ARM use an Address Space ID (ASID) to isolate processes.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a check for whether the CPU is in ring0 or not.  The CPU doesn't really know about processes: It doesn't matter how you got into ring 0, just that the CPU is currently executing kernel code.  (i.e. could run privileged instructions).

See Margaret's more detailed answer for the full details.

And yes, all access to memory even inside the kernel is by mapping it to a virtual address.  Kernels don't disable paging temporarily to access a specific physical address.  Note that Linux (and many other kernels) keep kernel pages locked into memory, and don't swap them out to disk, but they are still paged.

Comment: then does it mean that when we first check for CPL and it has a value 3, then no memory access will be allowed, regardless of whether the PTE S/U is 0 or 1 ?

Comment: @ijuio How could a program even be started without be allowed to perform any memory access (fetch of instructions included)? See my response to your comments below my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Margaret, I'm not that familiar with x86 PTE details so I couldn't make sense of that comment.  I thought maybe it was a sensible question that I was misunderstanding.